# CGRect as relative layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project at the moment, which requires a custom layout for a cell.

I've written the WP and Droid layouts, but stuck on iOS. The layout is pretty simple:

- Two columns, two rows. Rows are same height, first column is 96px wide and rest is taken by the second
- The first column is filled in by a number, spanning both rows
- The first row of the second column is filled by a title
- The second row of the second column is filled by a detail text, aligned left, and a date, aligned right.
- If the detail text is too long, it is trunkated, date is always displayed

Now for this, I wrote a custom renderer, which uses native elements (XamForms' ViewCell is extremely slow, 6x slower than e.g. TextCell or ImageCell). But on iOS, the only platform I've never really worked with, I ran into a problem.

I've created a class, inheriting from UITableViewCell, and added 4 labels to it: titleLabel, detailLabel, dateLabel, and bigNumLabel (latter being the first column's content).

I fill these labels, and add them to the Subviews, but when it gets to actually assigning them to an area, I'm pretty much shot. I'm using the following code:

`public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            bigNumLabel.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 96, 96);
            titleLabel.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(96, 12, 300, 38);
            detailLabel.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(96, 62, 300, 38);
            dateLabel.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(396, 62, 100, 38);
        }`

Now, the only issue I have is, I'm used to WP's (and XamForms') uber-simple relative layouts. On WP, I could make a grid, two columns, two rows, and align the data relatively - bigNumLabel in row0 column0, with rowspan2, titleLabel in row0 column1, aligned left, detailLabel in row1 column1, aligned left, and dateLabel in row1 column1 aligned right. On iOS, however, I have to specify down to a pixel level - how is it easier than WP then? Why do people perfer this old system instead of a truly flexible layout?

But that is not my question at the moment. Rather, I'm asking, how to align these parts so that they don't overlap, and are not fixed at a given pixel - but rather as a flow?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [**Auto Layout**](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/) to keep your label align and not overlapped. Since you may be already using native view for the `UITableViewCell`, you may consider using the designer for easier control over the *constraints* in Auto Layout.

Comment: As I'm using Xamarin.Forms, I'm not sure if I can use a designer-made element - all samples so far have been code-behind only, and my little to no experience in iOS development does not help either.